# Booting from LiveUSB stops at purple screen

Tags: boot, live-usb

I followed the instructions for creating a bootable USB stick. When I attempt to boot from the USB, however, Ubuntu will not fully run.

I am able to get a plain purple screen with the word Ubuntu in orange centered on the screen. Have I missed a step or have I done something wrong?

Comment: Try it http://askubuntu.com/q/162075/35775

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot that might be wrong if it just freezes there. One thing you might try is to use Ubuntu in its fail-safe mode. You can do so (from last I remember) by hitting F4 on the Ubuntu menu, and selecting fail-safe mode. This will run the live CD in "safe graphics" mode which is generally the problem with Live CD environments.

One thing you can do to troubleshoot this problem is to press F8 when the purple screen appears. This will show you the boot process allowing you to see exactly where the boot process hangs.

Comment: I took your advice and pressed F8 to see where the boot process hangs up.  It gets to a point where is says it is missing 2 firmware files.  It says error b43-phy0 b43/ucode15.fw not found and b43-open/ucode15.fw not found.  It gives a website to install a driver: please go to http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/b43#devicefirmware.  Would I download this on windows or try to incorporate it onto the UBS stick?

Comment: One thing you can try to do is to customize your LiveCD which can be done [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization)

Comment: Alternatively you might be able to try this, when booting press F4 and select the NOMODESET option for boot. Take a look here for more information: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132